# Windows 10 not showing files and folders in E drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I've partitioned my HDD into 4 parts - C, D, E, H drives. Recently E drive got full. After that, its files and folders disappeared. I also have dual boot Ubuntu. I can see the files and folders on Ubuntu. I deleted around 6 GB using Ubuntu, but still, any files or folders are not showing up in Windows. I tried optimizing the disk but it didn't help. Please help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Showing Hidden and Protected System Files with File Explorer

From **File Explorer**, click the **View** tab. From the **Options** drop down select **Change folder and search options**. When the **Folder Options** window opens, select the **View** tab from there, and then check **Show hidden files, folders, and drive**, *uncheck* **Hide empty drives**, and *uncheck* **Hide protected operating system files**, press **Apply**, **Ok** and now check the "E" drive from **File Explorer** and you can do with them whatever you want at this point for your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities for this happening.
But as one of them is a damaged file-system, I would advise to first take a
backup of the files. Since you cannot use Windows, use live Linux
to copy all the data to an external media.

Here are some possible actions :

**Reset folder and file attributes**

Open an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the command `E:`,
followed by the command `dir /ah`. If this shows your folders,
then enter the following command and wait for it to finish:

```
attrib -r -a -s -h
```

**Check disk**

In the same Command Prompt instance, enter the command :

```
chkdsk E:
```

This will only check the disk. If it finds errors, then enter the following
command to fix :

```
chkdsk E: /f
```

**Take Ownership**

The folders on the drive might have changed their owning account.
To restore yourself as the owner :

- In Windows Explorer, right-click `E` and choose Properties
- Click the Security tab
- Click the Advanced button
- If the owner is you or Administrators, all is OK
- Otherwise, click the Change button
- Click the Advanced button
- Click Find Now
- Double-click on Administrators (or Users for all users)
- Click OK
- Check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
- Click Apply

**Reset permissions**

- As above, go to Properties and then to the Security tab
- Click Edit
- Click Administrators
- If Full control is checked, stop
- Otherwise, check it and click Apply
- Repeat for Users

**Disable Fast Startup**

Some reports blame it for strange happening with the file system.
See this article:
[Turn On or Off Fast Startup in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Hi, chkdsk E: /f found errors, and fixed them. But still I cannot see files and folders  https://imgur.com/a/FLxLZoi